# Result of Calendar.getTime() changes unexpectedly

Tags: java

I was making a simple GUI calendar program and I started noticing that executing the following code somehow changes the date stored in the calendar instance:

```
private void set_calendar(){
    System.out.println(calendar.getTime().toString() );
    int d = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    day_list.setSelectedIndex(d-1);
    System.out.println(calendar.getTime().toString() );
}
```

How is this code (that only reads from the calendar) affecting the result of `calendar.getTime()`?

If you compile and run this program just hit the "Get Current Date" button and you should see the System.out.println results.

Here's the complete code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class small_calendar implements Runnable{

    private JFrame main_frame;
    private JPanel box_panel;
    private JPanel upper;
    private JPanel center;
    private Calendar calendar;
    private JComboBox<Integer> day_list;
    private final JButton get_current = new JButton("Get Current Date");

    public void run() {
        calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.setTime(new Date());

        main_frame = new JFrame("Small Calendar");
        main_frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        box_panel = new JPanel();
        box_panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(box_panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS) );

        day_list = new JComboBox<>();
        day_list.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<Integer>(get_days(calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))));
        day_list.setSelectedIndex(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)-1);
        day_list.setActionCommand("day_list");
        day_list.addActionListener(new change_date());
        upper = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        upper.add(day_list);

        center = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        get_current.addActionListener(new get_current_date());
        center.add(get_current);

        box_panel.add(upper);
        box_panel.add(center);
        main_frame.add(box_panel);
        main_frame.pack();
        main_frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private Integer[] get_days(int days) {
        Integer[] product = new Integer[days];
        for (int d = 0; d < days; d++)
            product[d] = d+1;
        return product;
    }

    private void set_calendar() {
        System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
        int m = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int d = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        day_list.setSelectedIndex(d-1);
        System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
    }

    private class change_date implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            JComboBox b = (JComboBox) ae.getSource();
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, b.getSelectedIndex());
        }
    }

    private class get_current_date implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            calendar.setTime(new Date());
            set_calendar();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[] ){
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new small_calendar());
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not "passing" anything, `calendar` is declared as an instance field, so it's "reference" is available to the entire instance of the class. Now, you should stop using `Calendar` and start making use of the new (and improved) `java.time` APIs instead

Comment: `unlock_fields` would probably be implemented as a `FocusListener` or better make use [`InputVerifier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html)

Comment: `year_field.addKeyListener(new no_nums() );` and ... no. Don't do this. `KeyListener` is never a good idea on a text component. To monitor for changes to the text field, use a `DocumentListener`, to filter the input use a `DocumentFilter` or just make use a `JFormattedTextField`, they even support dates

Comment: I don't follow what you're expecting to happen, but you have a single calendar and I gather the value of `calendar` is changing in some manner you are not expecting. I can't spot the bug, but you're changing `calendar` all over the place – `calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1`), a few calls to `calendar.add(..)`, `calendar.setTime(new Date())`, etc. – is one of them incorrect? Which one?

Comment: Make sure you understand the difference between an object instance and a reference to that object instance. Also, make sure you understand the difference between _pass-by-value_ and _pass-by-reference_. And finally, make sure you understand that Java is always _pass-by-value_, but for reference types (i.e., objects, not primitives), the "value" that is passed is the "reference" itself.

Comment: The problem is the code in `change_date.actionPerformed()`: the line `calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, b.getSelectedIndex() );` must be `calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, b.getSelectedIndex() + 1 );`

Comment: As a side note, now would be a good time to look up and start following Java naming conventions. The sooner you get into that habit, the better.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the code in `change_date.actionPerformed()` is wrong. If the value in `day_list` changes it doesn't set the correct day in the calendar but the day minus one (the selectedIndex starts from 0, but days start from 1).

Change the `change_date` class to

```
private class change_date implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        JComboBox b = (JComboBox)ae.getSource();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, b.getSelectedIndex() + 1);
    }
}
```

---

Why does this modify the date when you execute the code in `set_calendar()`?

As a reference, `set_calendar()` is defined as:

```
private void set_calendar(){
    System.out.println(calendar.getTime().toString() );
    int d = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    day_list.setSelectedIndex(d-1);
    System.out.println(calendar.getTime().toString() );
}
```

When this method calls `day_list.setSelectedIndex(d-1);` the `day_list` in turn calls the `actionPerformed` method of the connected ActionListener which in turn changes the date on the `calendar` instance.

Comment: Thanks guys. That helped out a lot. Will try to rewrite code so that its better.